# How to specify which compression to use in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

Hadoop has support for multiple compression codecs (e.g Gzip, LZ4, Snappy, etc). In what Hadoop config file do you specify which one exactly is to be used for jobs?

Answer (score 0):

It can be specified in the file core-site.xml. 
Example:

```
<property>
  <name>io.compression.codecs</name>
<value>org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BZip2Codec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DefaultCodec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec</value>
</property>
```

and in mapred-site.xml specify:

```
<property>
  <name>mapred.compress.map.output</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>mapred.map.output.compression.codec</name>
   <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BZip2Codec</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>mapred.output.compression.type</name>
<value>BLOCK</value>
</property>
```